# How is double hexDouble = 0xf.8p3 calculated as 15.5 * 2^3 ? (f.8 == 15.5 ??)

Tags: java, floating-point, hex

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double hexDouble = 0xf.8p3;
        System.out.println(hexDouble);
    }
}
```

How is double hexDouble = 0xf.8p3 calculated as 15.5 * 2^3  ? (f.8 == 15.5 ??)
Is f.8, read as 15.8 ??

Please tell me .......

Comment: Hexadecimal `f` is decimal 15. Hexadecimal `0.8` is `0.5` in decimal. `p3` is the binary exponent, so multiply by `2**3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` is 15 * 16<sup>0</sup> = 15, and `8` is 8 * 16<sup>-1</sup> = 0.5, so `f.8` *(hex)* is `15.5` *(decimal)*.